# Android resource linking failed due to Material TextView

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androidx, material-components-android

I want to use a material design in my android app. So I added this dependency in my project: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`. I have the same `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` as `27` and also using the same version of `AppCompat` Library: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`.
I also have google's maven repository as:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Also, my activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and I have parent theme `AppCompat` as `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` in `styles.xml`. Though I have all these conditions true, when I put the material `TextView` in `xml` as:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="textfield_label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I get an unrecognized-type view in design preview. Also, the app stops when tried to launch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="textfield_label">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your code actually helps the OP solves his problem, instead of _only_ providing a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Use the component `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`
- Use the component `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

For the 1st option you **have to import** the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) instead of Design Support Library.

> The Material Components for Android is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library.

For the 2nd option just change the component used with:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

For the material components for android you have to add the new library:

```
  dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
  }
```

and check [the doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) for the setup (you have to change the compileSdkVersion, the dependencies and the theme) and also you have to migrate to androidx library.

[Keep in mind that](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index):

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> **We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects**

Comment: I have tried it with `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` this dependency, but now I am getting `Android resource linking failed` error.

Comment: sorry, it was written by mistake. I have corrected my comment

Comment: @AshishJoshi check the Getting Started chapter linked in the answer and post your build.gradle. To use this lib you have to use compileSdk=28 or later, you have to remove the support libraries and you have to use the Material Components theme

Comment: Isn't it possible with compileSdk=27? If yes, What should be the steps?

Comment: @AshishJoshi you can't use compileSdk=27. Follow the steps here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: @AshishJoshi I've updated the answer with the 2 options. Keep in mind that support libraries are going EOL and the new firebase and google play services libraries require androidx.

Comment: It's actually required to upgrade your project to use the AndroidX libraries if you want to use the Material Components for Android library. Otherwise, just use the old design support library.

Comment: @Edric Exactly and also you have to update before or later.